# Achieving 'bounded genericity' in C++

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I'm transferring a project from Java to C++ and I have a problem with something relatively simple in Java.

I have a class `X` which is made to handle objects of type `Y` and objects inherited from `Y`. `X` often need to call a method from `Y`, say `kewl_method()`, and this method is different in each class inherited from `Y`. In Java I could do something like this:

```
public class X<y extends Y>
```

I would call `kewl_method()` in `X` without any headache and it would do what I want. If I understand correctly (I'm new to C++), there is no such thing as bounded genericity in C++, so if I use a template with `X` it would be possible to fill it with absolutely anything and I won't be able to call the variants of `kewl_method()`.

What is the best way to do this in C++ ? Using casts ?

Restriction: I cannot use boost or TR1.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[TravisG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/740202/travisg) (was: heishe) [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6803124/14089), as far as I am concerned.

But I want to comment on your question:

> so if I use a template with X it would be possible to fill it with absolutely anything

No, because it wouldn't compile without an accessible `kewl_method`.

You have to remember that in Java, bounded genericity is less about limiting the types accepted by your generic class as you seem to believe, and more about giving the generic class a more complete information on its generic type T to be able to validate the call to its methods at compile time.

In C++, this feature is provided as-is and where-used by the compiler: In a way similar to duck typing, but resolved at compile-time, the compiler will accept the compilation of the method only if the generic type class has access to the `kewl_method`.

For an example of 4 classes:

```
class X
{
    public : virtual void kewl_method() { /* etc. */ }
} ;

class Y : public X
{
    public : virtual void kewl_method() { /* etc. */ }
} ;

class Z
{
    public : virtual void kewl_method() { /* etc. */ }
} ;

class K
{
    public : virtual void wazaa() { /* etc. */ }
} ;
```

## Normal C++ solution

With C++ templates, you can feed your templated class A:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
    public :
        void foo()
        {
            T t ;
            t.kewl_method() ;
        }
} ;
```

... with the class X, Y and Z, but not K, because :

- X : it implements `kewl_method()`
- Y : it publicly derives from X, which implements `kewl_method()`
- Z : it implements `kewl_method()`
- K : it doesn't implements `kewl_method()`

... which is much more powerful than Java's (or C#'s) generics. The user code would be :

```
int main()
{
    // A's constraint is : implements kewl_method
    A<X> x ; x.foo() ; // OK: x implements kewl_method
    A<Y> y ; y.foo() ; // OK: y derives from X
    A<Z> z ; z.foo() ; // OK: z implements kewl_method
    A<K> k ; k.foo() ; // NOT OK : K won't compile: /main.cpp error:
                       //   ‘class K’ has no member named ‘kewl_method’
    return 0;
}
```

You need to call the `foo()` method to block the compilation.

## What if constraints are *really* needed?

If you want to limit it explicitly to classes inheriting from X, you must do it yourself, using code (*until the [C++ concepts](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Concepts_%28C%2B%2B%29) are standardized... They missed the C++0x deadline, so I guess we will have to wait for the next standard...*)

If you *really* want to put constraints, there are multiple ways. <s>While I know about it, I'm not familiar enough with the [SFINAE](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) concept to give you *the solution*, but</s> I can still see two ways to apply constraints for your case (*while they were tested for g++ 4.4.5, could someone wiser validate my code?*):

### Add a unused cast?

The B class is similar to the A class with one additional line of code:

```
template<typename T> // We want T to derive from X
class B
{
    public :
        void foo()
        {
            // creates an unused variable, initializing it with a
            // cast into the base class X. If T doesn't derive from
            // X, the cast will fail at compile time.
            // In release mode, it will probably be optimized away
            const X * x = static_cast<const T *>(NULL) ;

            T t ;
            t.kewl_method() ;
        }
} ;
```

Which, when B::foo() is called, would compile only if `T*` can be cast into `X*` (which is only be possible only through public inheritance).

The result would be :

```
int main()
{
    // B's constraint is : implements kewl_method, and derives from X
    B<X> x ; x.foo() ; // OK : x is of type X
    B<Y> y ; y.foo() ; // OK : y derives from X
    B<Z> z ; z.foo() ; // NOT OK : z won't compile: main.cpp| error:
                       //      cannot convert ‘const Z*’ to ‘const X*’
                       //      in initialization
    B<K> k ; k.foo() ; // NOT OK : K won't compile: /main.cpp error:
                       //      cannot convert ‘const K*’ to ‘const X*’
                       //      in initialization
    return 0 ;
}
```

But, as the A example, you need to call the `foo()` method to block the compilation.

### Add a homegrown "constraint" with a class?

Let's create a class expressing a constraint on its constructor:

```
template<typename T, typename T_Base>
class inheritance_constraint
{
    public:
        inheritance_constraint()
        {
            const T_Base * t = static_cast<const T *>(NULL) ;
        }
} ;
```

You'll note the class is empty, and its constructor does nothing, so chances are good it will be optimized away.

You would use it as in the following example:

```
template<typename T>
class C : inheritance_constraint<T, X> // we want T to derive from X
{
    public :
        void foo()
        {
            T t ;
            t.kewl_method() ;
        }
} ;
```

The private inheritance means your "inheritance_constraint" would not screw with your code, but still, it expresses at compile time a constraint that would stop the compilation for a class T that don't derives from X:

The result would be :

```
int main()
{
    // C's constraint is : implements kewl_method, and derives from X
    C<X> x ; // OK : x is of type X
    C<Y> y ; // OK : y derives from X
    C<Z> z ; // NOT OK : z won't compile: main.cpp error:
             //      cannot convert ‘const Z*’ to ‘const X*’
             //      in initialization
    C<K> k ; // NOT OK : K won't compile: /main.cpp error:
             //      cannot convert ‘const K*’ to ‘const X*’
             //      in initialization
    return 0 ;
}
```

The problem is that it relies on inheritance and constructor call to be effective.

### Add a homegrown "constraint" with a function?

This constraint is more like a static assert, tested when the method is called. First, the constraint function:

```
template<typename T, typename T_Base>
void apply_inheritance_constraint()
{
    // This code does nothing, and has no side effects. It will probably
    // be optimized away at compile time.
    const T_Base * t = static_cast<const T *>(NULL) ;
} ;
```

Then the class using it:

```
template<typename T>
class D
{
    public :
        void foo()
        {
            // Here, we'll verify if T  inherits from X
            apply_inheritance_constraint<T, X>() ;

            T t ;
            t.kewl_method() ;
        }
} ;

int main()
{
    // D's constraint is : implements kewl_method, and derives from X
    D<X> x ; // OK : x is of type X
    D<Y> y ; // OK : y derives from X
    D<Z> z ; // NOT OK : z won't compile: main.cpp error:
             //      cannot convert ‘const Z*’ to ‘const X*’
             //      in initialization
    D<K> k ; // NOT OK : K won't compile: /main.cpp 2 errors:
             //      ‘class K’ has no member named ‘kewl_method’
             //      cannot convert ‘const K*’ to ‘const X*’
             //      in initialization
    return 0 ;
}
```

But, as the A and B example, you need to call the `foo()` method to block the compilation.

### Conclusion

You'll have to choose between one of the methods above, according to your specific needs.

But usually, as far as I am concerned, I find all this quite overkill, and I would use the first, simpler solution above.

### Edit 2011-07-24

Added another section with the code to express the constraint through a simple function call.

In the "Add a unused cast?" section, I replaced the reference cast `X & x = t ;` with the pointer cast (as in the other sections), which I believe is better.

And to give Caesar its due, the pointer cast was originally inspired by a line of code in the [now deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803100/achieving-bounded-genericity-in-c/6803214#6803214) of [Jonathan Grynspan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/265530).

Comment: You may want to remove your reference to SFINAE since SFINAE is all about *avoiding* a hard-error to e.g. help with overload resolution.

Comment: @Luc Danton : As I said, I'm not familiar enough with the concept, but I believe that a more complete solution would use SFINAE to assert robust constraints on types. In my 2nd example, I believe overloading a cast operator could deceive my cast to the reference to the base class, for example. Still, I'll follow your suggestion and "cross" the line. Thanks!

Comment: Nice. In the first example, you could put the conversion into a default constructor so you wouldn't *have to* call foo().

Comment: However, no IDE will give you the intellisense you need with this kind of check. In java, if you have <T extends X>, the IDE will show you methods you can use on T t; in C++ you just get nothing. Compile time might be better than runtime, but intellisense realtime error reporting is better still, and C++ lags behind in that.

Comment: @masterxilo : `In the first example, you could put the conversion into a default constructor` : It changes nothing as one would need the default constructor called to have it constrain the class use. The second example is the right one for current C++.

Comment: @masterxilo : `Compile time might be better than runtime, but intellisense realtime error reporting is better still` : The addition of concepts (or concepts lite) will make it easier and clearer both for the code reader and the IDE to detect the error at both compile time (clearer error messages) and realtime intelliense (easier to analyze for the IDE). It is currently a TS, so it should be official in 2017 or before. Note that I prefer compile time error + zero runtime cost to intellisense error + runtime cost (because, you know, virtual dispatch from using an OO interface).

Comment: @paercebal Sure that's cool. I have to read up on this "concepts" proposal. Ideally of course IntelliSense errors will be repeated as Compiler Errors such that the "intellisense error + runtime cost" case doesn't occur.

Comment: @paercebal I know I'm late to the game, but what about `static_assert(std::is_base_of<Y, Type>::value, "some error message to the compiler");` with `Y` being the original user's `Y` and `Type` being the template parameter? This would belong in the constructor of `X`, of course. `is_base_of` is defined in `type_traits`.

Answer (score 4):

Just type it like this:

```
template<class T>
void method()
{
   T t;
   t.kewl_method();
}
```

If you use it in a wrong way, your compiler will give you an error saying, kewl_method() is not a member of [type of T].

Comment: Your second example is illegal in C++. Non-type template arguments must be of integral type!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly making `Y::kewl_method` virtual would be a good translation from Java. You would than overload it in the classes derived from `Y`.

Comment: Indeed. Polymorphism can be done in several ways, and virtual methods and inheritance is a basic one. Better answer than the ones who try to do template tricks just because the word _generics_ is in the title, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

The construct you're referring to in Java is generics. The closest corresponding thing found in C++ is templates.
So the closest translation of what you presented here in C++ would be

```
template<class T>
class X
{
    // Here you use T as Y or type derived from it
    // for example
    void method(T& y)
    {
        y.kewl_method();
    }
};
```

Usage is as follows:

```
X<Y> a;
```

Or if you have derived from `Y` type say `Z`:

```
class Z : public Y {
  // ...
};
```

You can as well use

```
X<Z> b;
```

This is acceptable. Templates are duck typed in C++, i.e. you can call any method of type `T` and it will be correct as long as the actually specified type has this method.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to enforce that the template argument passed to your class template be inherited from a certain `class Y`. I should note that it is very unfortunate that you can't use boost. I'll provide a solution ***with*** boost.

```
template <class T, bool OK> class XImpl; //no definition, just declaration
template <class T> class XImpl<T, true> //partial specialization
{
    //here goes your real class definition
};
template <class T> class X : public XImpl<T, boost::is_base_and_derived<Y, T>::value >
{}; //if T isn't derived from Y, compilation will fail because you are trying to 
    //inherit from an incomplete (undefined) type
```

The only `boost` part we used was `is_based_and_derived` metafunction. You can look in boost sources, see how it's implemented, and implement it yourself. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Use a template but put a restriction on the types it work on:

```
template<typename T>
void
X::some_member(T& t)
{
    // Triggers a compile-time error if/when T is not derived from Y
    STATIC_ASSERT(( is_base_of<Y, T> ));
    t.kewl_method();
}
```

Since you're not using Boost you're going to have to implement `STATIC_ASSERT` and `is_base_of`. The first one is somewhat easy but the second one not as such (although you can use a `convertible<T, Y>` trait as an approximation).