# C++ Template Filter

Tags: c++11, templates, ubuntu

I just recently started working with c++ templates in order to use a template I know you do 
`template<typename T> class MyClass`, but how do I apply a filter? In C# you can do 
`public class MyClass<T> where T:filterClass` and in Java it's 
`public class MyClass<T extends/implements filterClass>`. I've tried following the tutorial at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a174071k.aspx but my compiler doesn't recognize the flag `-clr` or the keywords `generic` and `where`. I've looked on cppreference.com and cplusplus.com and couldn't find anything. Using the `--version` option on my compiler returns `g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu~16.04.1) 5.4.0 20160609`. I am also using c++11 and would prefer not to use external libraries.

Comment: What do you want to filter on?  You want the class to have a particular function before the template can be instantiated?  Or a particular base class?  Or something else?

Comment: Base class so I can run methods

Comment: If I understand your correctly, you're looking for ways to specify type bounds for templates. This question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803100/achieving-bounded-genericity-in-c

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I wanted.